# MudBlazor - Toggling the dark theme switches the start and end directions

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

This is my empty layout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ISyncLocalStorageService LocalStorage

<MudRTLProvider RightToLeft="false">
    <MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@isDarkTheme" Theme="theme" />
    <MudDialogProvider />
    <MudSnackbarProvider />

    <CascadingValue Value="@themeChanged">
        <CascadingValue Value="@isDarkTheme">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
    </CascadingValue>
</MudRTLProvider>

@code {
    MudTheme theme = new();
    bool isDarkTheme = true;

    EventCallback _themeChanged = EventCallback.Empty;
    EventCallback themeChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (_themeChanged.Equals(EventCallback.Empty))
                _themeChanged = EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, ToggleTheme);
            return _themeChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (LocalStorage.ContainKey(nameof(isDarkTheme)))
        {
            isDarkTheme = LocalStorage.GetItem<bool>(nameof(isDarkTheme));
        }
    }

    void ToggleTheme()
    {
        isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme;
        LocalStorage.SetItem<bool>(nameof(isDarkTheme), isDarkTheme);
    }
}
```

This is my main layout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@layout EmptyLayout

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="8">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" OnClick="@DrawerToggle" />
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton OnClick="ThemeChanged" Color="Color.Inherit" Icon="@(IsDarkTheme ? Icons.Filled.LightMode : Icons.Outlined.DarkMode)" />
        <MudIconButton Color="Color.Inherit" Icon="@Icons.Filled.Logout" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="drawerOpen" Elevation="8" ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Always" Anchor="Anchor.Start">
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="px-4 py-6">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool drawerOpen = true;

    [CascadingParameter]
    public bool IsDarkTheme { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter]
    public EventCallback ThemeChanged { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // ...
    }

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        drawerOpen = !drawerOpen;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but when I toggle the dark theme the start and end directions get switched (note the `Anchor="Anchor.Start"`).

[image]

I have this problem with other components as well like table pager and tab component with position on start.

I don't know if this is a bug or I am using incorrect settings.